# How can I add a Drupal Commerce Fee programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, module, commerce

I know how to add a line item programmatically, but I can't seem to find a way to specifically add a custom commerce fee in PHP. Commerce fees seem to register in two locations in the order array: Once under commerce_line_items, and once under commerce_order_total (See attached image). They are different than a regular line item in that they don't show up as products, but rather in the order totals box at the end of the order.  The fee shown in the attachment is one that has been entered using the Edit form in the admin section. I need to add one in code. Any ideas? [image]